# Gradle Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When adding

```
compile 'org.codetome:hexameter-core:3.0.0'
```

to my *build.gradle* file it syncs correctly, but when android studio tries to build the app this error shows up

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/INDEX.LIST

File1: /home/caerisse/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19/539df70269cc254a58cccc5d8e43286b4a73bf30/mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
File2: /home/caerisse/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.apple/AppleJavaExtensions/1.4/c586cd0b44cae8c0239a977277f99d08d751a482/AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar
```

I tried to add things similar to

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

as said in other similar questions, but it doesn't help...
In particular adding

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
```

generates the following errors:

```
Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex '/home/caerisse/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/3136ca936f64c9d68529f048c2618bd356bf85c9/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar' to '/home/caerisse/Development/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/debug/folders/1000/10/xml-apis-1.0.b2_1f18eecc5b9a7e9ac650cdcfa1d1700f8ccc005b'
```

There is nothing else in my *build.gradle*, except what android studio puts in its own.

Comment: You didn't exclude the mentioned file... `META-INF/INDEX.LIST`

Comment: I did, I forgot to mention it specifically, that generated a lot of error having to do with core libraries, apparently it's a important file.

Comment: No, thats how to get rid of the merge error, the new error is that your library has a javax.* class and Android doesn't like those

Comment: Oh, guess there is nothing to do now, since the library isn't mine, Thanks!